# How to control ONLY Primary Monitor (non-touch) in Windows 10 with Touchscreen Monitor

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, touchscreen

I would like to ask you guys - How to control ONLY Primary Monitor in Windows 10 with Touch Screen. WHen I bought my DELL touchscreen the touch controled the primary monitor only so if this touch screen were not primary it controlled another non touch screen. I changed it in Windows Control Panel - PC Tablet Settings -> Configuration. BUT... there is no way back there.

I would really appreciate ANY help!

Cheeers!

Comment: What exactly is the name of the option you changed?

Comment: Have you used a mouse (not touch) to manage the options?

Comment: I changed the settings in Control Panel -> Hardware and Sound -> Tablet PC Settings and then Settings/Configuration. I tried so many options including not touching touchscreen during calibration but there is always only touch screen working can't go back to touching the touchscreen as secondary monitor and controling other one (set as primary). I am stuck at this and would really apreciate any help!